# How to ensure one thread starts before another thread?

Tags: java, multithreading

Suppose we have two threads T1 and T2. I want to start T2 after T1 but not when T1 completes.

Comment: If these threads run concurrently, what about T1 makes it necessary that it starts first?

Comment: Just start T2 from the `run()` of T1.

Comment: What is your use case for doing this? This sounds like a case of the [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: If something has to happen before you start `T1`, then wait until that happens until you start `T1`. Ideally, have the code that makes that thing happen start `T1`. Alternatively, have `T1` wait for that thing to happen. Basically -- do it however you want.

Comment: just call t2.start() after calling t1.start(). To help guarantee t2 starts after t1, put a Thread.sleep() for a few msec as the first thing in your run method for t2.

Answer (score 3):

When you create the threads, they by default hold the priority of 5. Thus in your case, T1 & T2 will hold priority of 5 and scheduler may pick any of them at runtime.

To ensure your T1 runs before T2, try setting the priority of T1 higher than thread T2. The method setPriority(int value) can be helpful in getting this done.
For example : T1.setPriority(10).

This way, scheduler would always run T1 first.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not entirely clear, but you might want to look into [mutex locks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutual_exclusion), which work kind of like the example given below. Except with threads you'd want to use the [Lock](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/newlocks.html) class.

```
public class ThreadingTest {
    private Thread t1, t2;
    private boolean completed;

    public ThreadingTest(){
        t1 = new Thread(new Runnable(){
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Thread.sleep(1000);

                mutex();
            }
        });
        t2 = new Thread();

        completed = false;
    }

    public void doStuff(){
        t1.start();

        if(!completed)
            t2.start();
    }

    public void mutex(){
        completed = true;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        new ThreadingTest();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean "start?"

What's wrong with this?

```
Thread t1 = ...;
Thread t2 = ...;

t1.start();
t2.start();
```

That literally *starts* t1 before starting t2, but maybe there is something you need the first thread to *do* before the second thread can be started?

RE350 and igreen both had the same good idea, which could be implemented like this:

```
Thread t2 = ...;

Thread t1 = new Thread(new Runnable(){
    @Override
    public void run() {
        doTheThingThatNeedsToBeDoneFirst();
        t2.start();
        doTheRest();
    }
});

t1.start();
```

Or if there's some reason you can't do it that way, then it would be only slightly more complex to use a high-level synchronization object such as a Semaphore  (I think this is what David Schwartz suggested):

```
Semaphore semaphore = new Semaphore(0);

Thread t2 = ...;

Thread t1 = new Thread(new Runnable(){
    @Override
    public void run() {
        doTheThingThatNeedsToBeDoneFirst();
        semaphore.release();
        doTheRest();
    }
});

t1.start();
semaphore.acquire();
t2.start();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the Join method.... call it in body of a one method

The join method allows one thread to wait for the completion of another. If t is a Thread object whose thread is currently executing,

t.join();